# No such file or directory: './dataset/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'

Tags: python, csv, directory, dataset, google-colaboratory

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/AIP
```

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/AIP' /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks`

```
import os
import os.path
import requests

from scipy.integrate import odeint
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler


%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'

sns.set(style='whitegrid',font_scale=0.6)
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6,4
register_matplotlib_converters()
```

```
# DATA
URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/"
CONFIRMED="time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv" 
DEATH="time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv"
RECOVERED="time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv"
```

```
# Fixed random seed 
RANDOM_SEED = 42 np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED) torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
```

```
# Download dataset from GitHub which was provided by the Johns Hopkins University Center for Systems Science and Engineering (JHU CSSE).
if not os.path.isfile(f"./dataset/{CONFIRMED}"):
    for name in [CONFIRMED, DEATH, RECOVERED]:
        url = os.path.join(URL, name)
        r = requests.get(url)
        file_csv = open(os.path.join("./dataset", name), 'wb')
        file_csv.write(r.content)
        file_csv.close()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d47d8c7d4415> in <module>()
      4         url = os.path.join(URL, name)
      5         r = requests.get(url)
----> 6         file_csv = open(os.path.join("./dataset", name), 'wb')
      7         file_csv.write(r.content)
      8         file_csv.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './dataset/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'
```

I have trying to run this code but I have some problem please can someone help me to solve this

How can I solve this problem in google collab ??????

also how to correct this problem  No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/AIP' /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks

---

Answer (score 0):

Add `content` to path

```
file_csv = open(os.path.join("/content/dataset", name), 'wb')
```

Also check this file repository to check if your data is well downloaded in `content` file

[image]

Comment: thank you but they don't solve the problem

Comment: Does you code works in jupyter notebook?

Comment: thank you pyaj it work in Jupiter notebook